# Move object towards respective instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On pressing the 'A' key i'm trying to spawn an asteroid within a set area away from the camera and also spawn a missile to take down this exact asteroid which spawns from under the camera. Ideally you should be able to press this key super fast and each time have a new asteroid and missile prefab spawn, which then are destroyed upon collision.

Issue: currently each missile goes towards the first object with the 'asteroid' tag assigned, rather than each missile firing at its respective asteroid. Also, when pressing super fast, some asteroids are missed completely and while the missiles are destroyed, these missed asteroids are not.
Here is my code, any help would be much appreciated!

Assigned to Missile prefab:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class launch : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public float speed;
    void Update()
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Asteroid").transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Assigned to blank game object where asteroids spawn

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnAsteroid : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Asteroidprefab;
    public GameObject Missileprefab;

    public Vector3 center;
    public Vector3 ship;
    public Vector3 size;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            SpawnSpaceRock();
        }
    }

    public void SpawnSpaceRock()
    {
        Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x / 2, size.x / 2), Random.Range(-size.y / 2, size.y / 2), Random.Range(-size.z / 2, size.z / 2));

        Instantiate(Asteroidprefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(Missileprefab, ship, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
        Gizmos.DrawCube(center, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very bad to use any `Find` method in `Update` since it is quite expensive!

it also returns only the first found GameObject.

---

What you want instead is store a target reference in `launch` when you initialize it and use that one

**launch**

```
public class launch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Target;

    public float speed;
void Update()
{
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // Only collide with your specific target
        if (collision.gameObject != Target) return;
    
        Destroy(Target);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

**SpawnAsteroide**

```
// Hint of you use the correct component type here
// you don't even have to use GetComponent later
public launch MissilePrefab;
public GameObject Asteroideprefab;

//...

public void SpawnSpaceRock()
{
    Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x / 2, size.x / 2), Random.Range(-size.y / 2, size.y / 2), Random.Range(-size.z / 2, size.z / 2));

    // store reference of Instantiated GameObject
    var asteroide =  Instantiate(Asteroidprefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);

    // Store reference of Instantiated launch componemt
    var missile = Instantiate(Missileprefab, ship, Quaternion.identity);

    // Now set the taregt
    missile.Target = asteroid;
}
```

---

**Alternatively - single Update**

sometimes the performance is better if you don't have a lot of objects running individual `Update` methods but having only one central `Update` method controlling them all. In this case you could e.g. use a dictionary

in **SpawnAsteroide**

```
public float speed;

private Dictionary<launch, GameObject> MissileToAsteroid = new Dictionary<launch, GameObject>(); 

public void SpawnSpaceRock()
{
    Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x / 2, size.x / 2), Random.Range(-size.y / 2, size.y / 2), Random.Range(-size.z / 2, size.z / 2));

    // store reference of Instantiated GameObject
    var asteroide =  Instantiate(Asteroidprefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);

    // Store reference of Instantiated launch componemt
    var missile = Instantiate(Missileprefab, ship, Quaternion.identity);

    // Since launch is still responsible for different both objects
    // you still need to pass the reference
    missile.Target = asteroid;


    // Add to dictionary
    MissileToAsteroid [missile] = asteroid;
}
```

And than run it all in your central `Update` method

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        SpawnSpaceRock();
    }

    // TODO: Maybe later remove null elements for better performance

    // Run each move towards
    foreach(var kvp in MissileToAsteroid)
    {
        var missile = kvp.key;
        var asteroid = kvp.value;

        if(missile)
        {
            missile.transform.MoveTowards(missile.transform.possition, asteroid.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

and than let `launch` only handle the destroying of both objects (so remove the `Update` there)

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. When I run the single update version of this I receive the following error: "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'launch' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object." -- The first missile fires at the asteroid, but once it's hit the following missiles just fall into the abyss.

Comment: Wrapping the missiles transform line in a if statement to check if missile != null did the trick.

Comment: @JaydenAmenity yeah sorry I thought about that when I wrote that comment `// TODO: Maybe later remove null elements for better performance` and than I forgot to add the null check ^^ However it would still be better to also remove those "dirty" entries from the dictionary

Comment: no worries, your help perfectly accomplished what i was hoping to achieve and will allow me to continue with the project. But how would be best to remove these "dirty" entries from the dictionary, if you don't mind? - I'm not all that familiar with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In missle objects save target stone and use lists of missles and stones. Foreach missle in missle array move in Update